# What is the difference between formik.handleChange and formik.setFieldValue

Tags: reactjs, formik

In [formik](https://formik.org/), inside the property `onChange`, sometimes `onChange = {formik.handleChange}` is called and sometimes `onChange = {v => formik.setFieldValue('field', v)}` is called. Whats the difference between these two?

Is it possible to replace the use of `formik.setFieldValue` with just `formik.handleChange`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`handleChange` returns:

```
handleChange: (e: React.ChangeEvent<any>) => void
```

General input change event handler. This will update the `values[key]` where `key` is the event-emitting input's `name` attribute. If the `name` attribute is not present, `handleChange` will look for an input's `id` attribute. Note: "input" here means all HTML inputs.

`setFieldValue` returns:

```
setFieldValue: (field: string, value: any, shouldValidate?: boolean) => void
```

Set `values` imperatively. Calling this will trigger validation to run if `validateOnChange` is set to `true` (which it is by default). You can also explicitly prevent/skip validation by passing a third argument as `false`.

There can find [doc](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#setvalues-fields--field-string-any--shouldvalidate-boolean--void) where differences written.